# Sticky header with Dynamic Island or Notch in React Natvie

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I would like to create sticky header in my app. I used a FlatList with `stickyHeaderIndices` prop. It works fine with android devices and devices without Notch and Dynamic Island. But when it's devices with Notch or Dynamic Island, the content goes below it.

I tried to add some paddings to the content if dynamic island or notch exists, but it will be wrong initialy with design.

[image]

Comment: Do you use SafeAreaView ?

Comment: @mustafa-hsz , no, I don't use SafeAreaView, because I don't need it according to design

Comment: as you said you want to keep your content inside SafeArea.(notch and dynamic island are out of SafeArea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your code inside a SafeAreaView.

Here's an example of keeping a View component as the parent component.

```
return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
      <Image
        style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
        source={require("../../images/camera.png")}
      />
      <Text>Is this hidden?</Text>
    </View>
  );
```

And my Image and Text goes under the Dynamic Island or Notch.

[image]

But when I wrap the same in SafeAreaView my UI does not gets intervened.

```
return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <Image
          style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
          source={require("../../images/camera.png")}
        />
        <Text>Is this hidden?</Text>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

[image]